# Не запускается Ubuntu на VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация

я начинаю изучать линукс (сейчас на windows 10), скачала Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.22 и ubuntu 18.04.1, но запустить не смогла. После создания виртуальной машины не получается выбрать образ диска, где лежит ubuntu, потому что возникает такая ошибка: Функция аппаратной виртуализации включена для данной машины, но не поддерживается Вашим хостом. Для обеспечения работоспособности машины она должна быть выключена.

Я открываю настройки виртуальной машины, потом "система", потом "ускорение" и отключаю аппаратную визуализацию, но ошибка всё равно не исчезает. Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего это может быть и как можно исправить?

Comment: https://sdelaicomp.ru/programmy/funkciya-apparatnoj-virtualizacii-vklyuchena.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такая ошибка возникает, если у вас в системе уже установлен гипервизор. Скорее всего, у вас активирован гипервизор Hyper-V. Удалите его через Панель управления - Программы - Программы и компоненты - Включение и отключение компонентов Windows. Перезагрузитесь и запустите Virtual Box снова. Но!

Устанавливать Virtual Box имеет смысл только в том случае, если вы хотите осваивать графический шелл Gnome или KDE. Если же вы собираетесь работать в командной строке или отдельных приложениях, то для запуска линукса в Windows достаточно [активировать WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) - Windows Subsystem for Linux - и [установить Ubuntu из MS Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Этот вариант работает быстрее, чем Virual Box, и лучше интегрирован в Windows в плане обмена файлами.

Затем ещё можно установить X сервер и Windows Terminal, и пользоваться Linux почти нативно. На фотке терминал Gnome Terminal, запущенный в Ubuntu 18, установленном в WSL. В терминале рабочая папка `/mnt/c/Windows` ;)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]